# What is the maximum characters allowed in the option field in select tag in liferay 6.2 dynamic data list structure?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamic-data-list

I am not able to get the values to be displayed onto the ui side for the dynamic data list with the select options having long option values.
I can see the data being stored into the database for the long values, but it does not gets displayed onto the ui side.
Please find the attached screenshot for more detail.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where can i find the value for the limit of the option values for the select tags in dynamic data list?
How can i change the value to display my options with more characters?

Thanks in advance.